# Android formatting xml string loses its html tags

Tags: android, html, xml, string

I have a xml string below that contains html tags such as Bold and a hyperlink href.

```
<string name"example"><b>%1$s</b> has been added to your clipboard  and is valid until  <b>%2$s</b><a href="http://www.google.com">Please see our +T\'s and C\'s+ </a>   </string>
```

when i format the string to dynamically add some values it removes the bolded text and href I defined.

code below:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
Date date = new Date(text.getValidTo()); 
String text = String.format(getString(R.string_dialog_text), text.getCode(), simpleDateFormat.format(date), "£30");
```

I then apply it to a alert dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, onClickListener);
builder.setTitle(title);
builder.setMessage(text);
```

this worked fine if i dont format the text and directly use the string resource

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `Html.fromHtml`

```
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

when you apply the formatting, the `CharSequence` is converted back to `String`, and you need the `Spannable` with the html information.

From the doc:

> Sometimes you may want to create a styled text resource that is also
>   used as a format string. Normally, this won't work because the
>   String.format(String, Object...) method will strip all the style
>   information from the string. The work-around to this is to write the
>   HTML tags with escaped entities, which are then recovered with
>   fromHtml(String), after the formatting takes place.

try with `&lt;b>` in place of `<b>` and with `&lt;/b>` in place `</b>`

Comment: Hi i tried this approach and it still could not render he html tags placed on the text

Comment: it should be `&lt;a` and `&lt;/a>`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you want this

```
<resources>
<string name="our_string_key">
    <B>Title</B> <I>Italic</I><BR/>
    Content
</string>
</resources>
```

Then in that case you yse it as

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(R.String.our_string_key));
```

If in case you are getting errror then you can use it as

```
   textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.String.our_string_key)));
```

Comment: How you are trying to do it can you post same code.?